# How to Loop Through Folders and Subfolders in multilevel

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, web-scraping, async-await

I need to create an API with Node.js (and TypeScript just to use types, but no impact at all for this question) where the user inserts any GitHub Repo's link and the API returns via web scraping all files and their extensions, sizes and total of lines.

My code works well getting the top level files. I'm stuck with folders because they might have subfolders and more subfolders and more files inside them. And of course, there is no absolute number of how many levels it goes down nor how many files could be there.

**What did I try to do so far?**

1. Recursion. The problem is it is a higher level for me and I can't handle such task.
2. I prepared the code to be able to make the function call itself over and over, but it returns an error.

I'll post my code below, but if you want, feel free to get access to it at https://github.com/raphaelalvarenga/git-hub-web-scraping

**This the request structure (feel free to change the repo, like searching for facebook/react or any other, for example):**

[image]

**This is the controller:**
[image]

**IMPORTANT! Note the getRowData() method being called in the line 16 passing the HTML parameter got in line 13.**

**This is the getRowData module. I'm stuck at lines 37 and 38 where I exactly try to use recursion passing HREF atribbute to make a new request and calling getRowData() again inside itself.**

[image]

**And finally, this is the error:**

[image]

Just as a bonus, it's authorized the request take long time at first, but the subsequent requests shouldn't take too much to be executed. Any ideas?

Thanks for now.

EDIT:
I forgot to say that APIs to get data from GitHub aren't allowed.

Comment: Github has an [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). If you want to get all files from a repo recursively, you can use the [get a tree recursively API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively) : https://api.github.com/repos/mui-org/material-ui/git/trees/master?recursive=true

Comment: No API allowed in the challenge rules

Comment: "I'll post my code below", except you *didn't*,  You posted *images* of your code, and that's not at all the same thing.  Please always post the relevant code into your StackOverflow question.